# Toggling class names using classNameBindings in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

I'm new to emberjs and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how classNameBindings work.

Here's my current set up - http://jsfiddle.net/inquen/AXza5/

(this is how it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/inquen/N4WJS/)

The template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="doors">
 {{#view StandClear.DoorView class="left-door"}}<div class="door-window"></div>{{/view}}
 {{#view StandClear.DoorView class="right-door"}}<div class="door-window"></div>{{/view}}
</div>
<div class="door-closure-lamp"></div>
{{#view StandClear.DoorStateView}}
  Toggle Doors
{{/view}}
</div>
</script>​

StandClear = Ember.Application.create();
```

The JavaScript

```
StandClear.doorController = Ember.Controller.create({
   doorsOpen: true,
   toggleDoors:function(e){
   this.doorsOpen = (this.doorsOpen === false) ? true : false; 
   console.log(this.doorsOpen);
 }
});

StandClear.DoorView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName: 'div',
   classNames:['car-door'],
   classNameBindings: 'StandClear.doorController.doorsOpen',
})

StandClear.DoorStateView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName: 'button',
   classNames:['door-controller'],
   click:function(e){
   StandClear.doorController.toggleDoors();
 }
});
```

The class name binding works when the page is loaded, but doesn't change when the value it is bound to changes.

I feel there are a number of structural issues with my code as well, I'd appreciate some feedback on this as well.

Comment: The class name bindings value that is "true" or "false" will add or remove the class which is we have added.   In the example the classNameBindings will get true or false, but there is no class to add based on the value. Refer http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html

Comment: @Matt _Boolean value class name bindings whose property names are in a camelCase-style format will be converted to a dasherized format_.

So the classNameBinding `StandClear.doorController.doorsOpen` will evaluate to the class name `doors-open` if `StandClear.doorController.doorsOpen` evaluates to true, and blank otherwise.

Comment: Use get and set to retrieve or set values to the properties... http://jsfiddle.net/AXza5/2/ this works out

Comment: Thanks @SelvaGanesh I saw errors mentioning Ember.set and Ember.get in the console, but I wasn't sure how to proceed. Also do you have any tips on code structure?